# Local variable syntax error

Tags: mysql, c, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a procedure from the MySQL API in C. My query string is as follows (in the C code):

```
"CREATE PROCEDURE clockOut (taskID INT UNSIGNED) "
"BEGIN "
"DECLARE @username VARCHAR(8);"
"SELECT @username = userID FROM TaskItem WHERE id=taskID;"
"UPDATE TaskItem SET onClock=0,stopTime=NOW() "
"WHERE id=taskID AND userID=@username;"
"END"
```

This string will ultimately be transmitted with `mysql_query()`, which returns error code 1064, a syntax error. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You might like to RTFM here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html (as I just did and deleted my previous comment therefore) Mind the *delimiter*.

Comment: The delimiter isn't a problem in the C API, @alk. Other procedures with this syntax are created fine (I could paste if you want). This is the only one failing, and variables are the only thing different about it. The `DELIMITER //` syntax is only for the official MySQL CLI client, because the delimiter is used to tell the client (not the server) when the query is finished.

Comment: Ahok, .. so what about the `@`s isn't that Sybase SQL? Does the code also fail without the `@`s?

Comment: And ist there any particular reason you are using two statements?

Answer (score 1):

As @alk suggested, I removed the `@` syntax from my variables, and it worked fine.